# Xpath to return list of values

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XPATH `/OMRequest/Record/Customer/PhoneList/Phone/text()` which works well when there is only one `Phone` in `PhoneList`. However, I would like an XPath that returns all `Phone` within the `PhoneList`.

A sample XML is the following:

```
<OMRequest>
   <Record>
        <Customer>
            <PhoneList>
                <Phone>000000000</Phone>
                <Phone>000000000</Phone>
            </PhoneList>
            <CustomerId>424792716</CustomerId>
            <AccountNumber>1</AccountNumber>
            <ECPDId/>
            <ContractId/>
        </Customer>
    </Record>
</OMRequest>
```

Comment: `/OMRequest/Record/Customer/PhoneList/Phone/text()` returns all of them already. How are you executing the XPath? Show the calling code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alone, `/OMRequest/Record/Customer/PhoneList/Phone/text()` will already select multiple such text nodes if they exist in the document.

If you're only getting the first one, then you're likely passing the nodeset to another function, which is only operating on the first node of the nodeset (using XPath 1.0 terminology and constructs).

For example, in XPath 1.0,

```
string(/OMRequest/Record/Customer/PhoneList/Phone/text())
```

only takes the string value of the *first* of the selected text nodes:

```
7702958254
```

Other functions, and other calls from hosting languages, can behave similarly.

If you want to operate on all selected text nodes, in XPath 1.0 you'll have to iterate in the hosting language outside of XPath.   XPath 2.0 has sequences rather than nodesets and has additional options for operating on sequences within XPath itself.