# Can you get the string values of a node list from XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

The XPath function `string()` only returns the string value of the first node if it's fed a node list.
I'm using a selector that selects attributes:
`//a/@href`
This returns an array of `href` nodes, which you have to map into each node's string values.

Is there a way to do this inside the selector?
E.G. something like `//a/@href/string()`

Comment: Did you try `//a/@href/text()`?

Comment: @JaSON yes, it didn't work, but I'm testing on chrome devtools which must have xpath 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

You must iterate the node set in the hosting language to convert each to its string value.  `string()` will indeed only take the string value of the first member of any nodeset passed to it.

### XPath 2.0

Your requested XPath, `//a/@href/string()`, would work directly.

### See also

- [Xpath to return list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52408323/290085)
- [XPath text with children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41101974/290085)

Comment: Ohh I was using chrome's `$x()` notation, I guess it must be 1.0 because string() only returns a single string.

Comment: Correct, Chrome only implements XPath 1.0.